# Issue with CSS background image (Image not Showing)

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with a background image not showing.

I have a class that I've added to an anchor tag.

```
<a class="my-class"></a>
```

and the css for the class is:

```
.my-class {
    background:transparent url("../images/my-bg-image.png") no-repeat 0 center
 }
```

The problem is that the background image is not showing.

I know it's there because when I do this:

```
<a class="my-class">&NBSP;</a>
```

part of the image shows.

Anyone have any idea on how to make the whole image show without having to insert lots of `&nbsp;` 's please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<a>` tag is an **inline** element and without a content will not show the background, so You need to make it `display` as a `block` or `inline-block` element and then define the **size** of the element.

Try with:

```
.my-class {
    display:     block;
    width:       128px;
    height:      128px;
    background:  transparent url("../images/my-bg-image.png") no-repeat 0 center
}
```

For more information you can check the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) and the [display property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) on the [CSS 2.1 w3c standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/).

Also the sections [The width property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property) and [Computing widths and margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) have an explanation of why the element doesn't show the background on an empty inline element.

**Update:**

Also the **working draft** of the **CSS Box Model** is [available](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/) on the W3C site.

**Update 2:**

On a side note, relying only on a css background image for a link can have somme *accessibility issues*.

Comment: You could also use `min-width:<insert image width here>;` if you want the size to be flexible.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs, yes, but I just was thinking that the root problem here was about **understanding how the box model** works and the difference between `inline`, `block`, and `inline-block` elements :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign a width to your anchor. Inline elements have no width if they have no content.

```
.my-class {
    background:transparent url("../images/my-bg-image.png") no-repeat 0 center;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Edit:** and it seems without any content at all it is also necessary to set a height and `display:inline-block`.  This causes the element to think of itself internally as a block element, but act externally as inline.

Comment: I tried: .my-class {
    background:transparent url("../images/my-bg-image.png") no-repeat 0 center; width:20px; height:20px;
 } but nothing changed.

Answer (score 5):

The element has a zero-width because it has no content at all. If the image contains useful information (and it really should, it is used as a link!), you should put some text inside the link and use any image replacement technique you like, for example:

HTML:

```
<a class="my-class">It‘s awesome!</a>
```

CSS:

```
.my-class {
    background:transparent url("../images/my-bg-image.png") no-repeat 0 center;
    display: inline-block; /* create a block element behaving like an inline element */
    text-indent: -1000em; /* move the inner text outside of the link */
    overflow: hidden; /* prevent text visibility */
    width: 200px; /* image width */
    height: 16px; /* image height */
}
```